# SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input | discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

So, I was making my Discord bot as usual, and just at a moment this problem started popping up without any reason at all. It says the problem is caused by the end of the line, which is where my token is. I have no idea what exactly is causing it. I even looked at the code from the official Discord docs, everything should be right. Maybe I made a typo or something, no idea. I even regenerated the token itself multiple times and checked if it was right but it doesn't seem to work.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const Client = new Discord.Client();

const client = new Discord.Client();
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

const cooldowns = new Discord.Collection();

Client.on('ready', ()=>{
console.log("ready to go");
});

Client.on('message', message =>{
    if (!message.content.startsWith("e!") || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice("e!".length).trim().split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (!client.commands.has(command)) return;

    try {
        client.commands.get(command).execute(message, args);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        message.channel.send('An error happened while trying to execute that command. Consult the owner of the bot for possible fixes.');
}

Client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {

  const channel = member.guild.channels.cache.find(ch => ch.name === 'general');

  if (!channel) return;

  channel.send(`Welcome to the server, ${member}`);

})

Client.login("My token");
```

Comment: Could you add the full error message along with its stack trace to the question?

Comment: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
[90m    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1054:16)[39m
[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1102:27)[39m
[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)[39m
[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)[39m
[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14)[39m
[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)[39m
[90m    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47[39md

Comment: it seems like the problem with the library itself, I'm not sure as I'm pretty new to javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Placing this code into visual studio code instantly gave me this error[image]

You seemed to have removed `})` at the bottom of your file. I'd suggest using vscode as it tells you about these errors.

fixed code

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const Client = new Discord.Client();

const client = new Discord.Client();
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

const cooldowns = new Discord.Collection();

Client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log("ready to go");
});

Client.on('message', message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith("e!") || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice("e!".length).trim().split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (!client.commands.has(command)) return;

    try {
        client.commands.get(command).execute(message, args);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        message.channel.send('An error happened while trying to execute that command. Consult the owner of the bot for possible fixes.');
    }

    Client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {

        const channel = member.guild.channels.cache.find(ch => ch.name === 'general');

        if (!channel) return;

        channel.send(`Welcome to the server, ${member}`);

    })
});

Client.login("My token");
```

Comment: I probably removed it accidentally. Thank you very much. I will check vscode out thanks